# Spring Cloud Stream Listener not pausing / waiting for the messages in Integration Testing Code

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-cloud-stream

I am having a Application which connects to RabbitMQ through Spring Cloud Stream, which works prefectly.

For **Integration test cases** i am trying to use the sample - https://github.com/piomin/sample-message-driven-microservices/blob/master/account-service/src/test/java/pl/piomin/services/account/OrderReceiverTest.java

However, in my case my application sends back 3 messages in some time Interval. So if i put the below Lines, it fetches the messages, but if the there is a delay in getting the messages.

```
 int i = 1;
    while (i > 0) {
        Message<String> received = (Message<String>) collector.forChannel(channels.statusMessage()).poll();
        if (received != null) {
            LOGGER.info("Order response received: {}", received.getPayload());
        }
    }
```

1. So Instead of my custom polling, is there any way i can wait and Poll for my messages, and stop when i get those ?
2. I want to get the pick Messages based on the Response Routing Key to different Channels. Is it possible ? 
   --> Example: If the routingKey is "InProcess" , it should go to Inprocess Method.

Answer (score 0):

1) Your question is not at all clear, expand on it and explain exactly what you mean.

2) Routing keys are used within Rabbit to route to different queues, they are not used within the framework to route to channels or methods.

You can, however, use a `condition` on the `@StreamListener` (match on the `headers['amqp_receivedRoutingKey`]`), but it's better to route messages to different queues instead.